# (Principiante PIEDRA PAPEL O TIJERA) addEventListener para conjunto de botones

Tags: javascript, html, click

Tengo una función `eleccionJuagador()` que la paso por el `onclick` en `html` en 3 botones, (o sea la misma función para los tres), y esta a través del `id` me devuelve el texto.

Lo que quiero es hacerlo completamente con `js` utilizando `addEventListner`, pero no logro dar con la solución. Intenté utilizando `querySelectorAll` y luego haciendo un `forEach` con el `addEventListener` pasando el evento `click` y la función.

CODIGO HTML

```html
<div id="choise">
            <button class="botones" id="piedra" onclick="eleccionJugador(this)">
                Piedra
            </button>
            <button class="botones" id="papel" onclick="eleccionJugador(this)">
                Papel
            </button>
            <button class="botones" id="tijera" onclick="eleccionJugador(this)">
                Tijera
            </button>
        </div>
```

CÓDIGO JS

```js
function eleccionJugador(boton){
    let id = boton.id;
    choiseUser = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
    return console.log(choiseUser);
}
```

LO QUE INTENTÉ

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".botones");
botones.forEach(boton => boton.addEventListener("click", this.eleccionJugador()));
```

Comment: Remueve los `onclick` de tu HTML, y luego prueba con `botones.forEach(boton => boton.addEventListener("click", () => eleccionJugador(boton)));`

Comment: Aquí no hay error tipográfico, no veo motivo de cierre en esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo hacerlo con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) usando, tal como lo intentas, [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y añadiendo el manejador de evento a cada botón.

Sin embargo, lo que necesitas hacer es detectar sobre qué botón se ha hecho clic, para así capturar el valor correspondiente.

Puedes usar el mismo manejador de evento para cada botón, y para identificar el botón sobre el que se ha hecho clic o para obtener el valor correspondiente a dicho botón, debes usar el objeto [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) o incluso el objeto [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), que siempre es parte del evento.

Así, cuando añades un manejador de evento a un elemento del DOM, tienes la posibilidad de obtener el Elemento que disparó dicho evento, inspeccionando el objeto `event` recibido en el manejador de evento, por ejemplo:

```js
boton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target; // <- target es el Elemento (boton) sobre el que se hizo clic
});
```

Entonces, podemos escribir un manejador de eventos reutilizable, ya que el mismo evento contendrá la información suficiente y necesaria para saber sobre qué botón se ha hecho clic.

Tu código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
function eleccionJugador(boton){
   const userChoice = boton.innerText;
   console.log(userChoice);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.botones').forEach((boton) => {
  boton.addEventListener('click', (event) => eleccionJugador(event.target));
});
```

```html
<div id="choise">
    <button class="botones" id="piedra">
        Piedra
    </button>
    <button class="botones" id="papel">
        Papel
    </button>
    <button class="botones" id="tijera">
        Tijera
    </button>
</div>
```

Como puedes observar, estoy usando una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) como manejador de evento, la cual recibe el objeto `event`, y se llama luego a la función `seleccionJugador()`, pasando como argumento el objeto `target` que contiene el `evento`. Así, el botón recibido por la función `seleccionJugador` será el que sea clicado.

También puedes observar que he eliminado del código [html](/questions/tagged/html) el atributo `onclick`, ya que no es necesario añadirlo si vas a usar [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para añadir los manejadores de evento. Además, es considerado buena práctica separar la capa de presentación (`html`) de la capa de lógica (`javascript`).

Por último, dado que el objeto `target` que es parte del evento, es a su vez el botón que se ha clicado, no hace falta capturar su valor de `id` sino que directamente puedo acceder a `innerText`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y aclare tus dudas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio! Tu respuesta y aclaraciones me sirvieron de mucho a parte de funcionar. Saludos!